# Get build number of triggering project in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-2

I configured a Jenkins project B to run when project A completes succesfully.

How can I find the buildnumber of A in the project B pipeline?

Answer (score 4):

If you just need the **last successful** build of A you can just read it from Jenkins:

http://JenkinsMaster:Port/job/MyJob/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber

If you need the build the triggered B you can use the [Parametized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) and use : 
TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_MyJob="Last build number triggered"

Comment: I want to know exactly the buildnumber of A that triggered B which might be different from the last succesful build. If I read the documentation correctly TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_ allows project A to figure out the buildnumber of B when triggered from A. In my case, project B needs to figure out project A's buildnumber.

Comment: You misunderstood me, so I'll try to explain better. instead of triggering B from A as a post build operation you can wrap it in job C. configuration of job C is quite simple - trigger A, block it until completion, when done check build status (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) and only if successful trigger job B, and send to job B the parameter "TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_JobA" which is the job triggered by C. I've tested it locally and it works like a charm :)

Comment: If it worked for you can you add this as the right answer? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Use the *Execute windows batch* or *Execute shell* build step to store the build version in a file during the build of project A - e.g. from a windows batch:

   ```
   echo "VARIABLEA=%BUILD_NUMBER%" > %WORKSPACE%\myartifact.properties:
   ```
2. Use the *Archive the artifacts* post build step to store the file against that build in project A
3. At the start of project B use the *Copy artifacts from another project* build step, point to project A and use the *Artifacts to copy* field to filter down to the file you created and choos *Last successful build* for the *Which build* field
4. Read the file in a shell script during the build of project A to pickup the build number

If you output the artifact in the format:

```
    VARIABLEA=${BUILD_NUMBER} 
    VARIABLEB=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

*and* you're using Linux on the Jenkins server, you could use the *source* command to make VARIABLEA and VARIABLEB available in that shell session, e.g.:

```
    source "${WORKSPACE}/myartifact.properties"
    echo ${VARIABLEA}
```

You could then do something with that variable in the shell script.

---

Alternately, you could simply use the *Trigger parameterized build on other projects* post build step (which I believe requires the Parameterized Trigger Plugin) on project A and setup project B to accept those parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the options. It strikes me that there isn't an option that allows project A to be unaware it is triggering downstream projects.

Comment: Yes, the first option would allow for that, you would configure project b to build when project a builds successfully under the build triggers of project b. You would need to copy the artifact/s from project a to pull the variable/s in.

Comment: to pull in the artifacts from A in B you need to know the build number of A which leads us to the problem we are trying to solve.

Comment: I've just updated the answer, in step 3 you would use the *Which build* field to determine the build to pull the artifact from which you'll probably just want to be the *lastest successful build* of project a. The artifact will have the build number of project A inside it.

Answer (score 0):

For pipeline:

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage{"trigger job"){
            steps{
                 script{
                     triggered_build = build job:"dummy-job",
                                       waitForStart: true
                     triggered_build_number = triggered_build.getNumber()
                     echo "triggered build: ${triggered_build}
                     echo "triggered build number : ${triggered_build_number}
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

kudos for @Venkat, OP from [how to get the build number from a triggered job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65332325/how-to-get-the-build-number-from-a-triggered-job)

Now you can access triggered build number and build name as a variable anywhere within the stage.

NOTE1: you need script step to invoke *.getNumber()* method

NOTE2: you need *waitForStart: true* or *wait: true*

I'm using here **build step** to trigger job: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/