# how to get the build number from a triggered job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

In my jenkins pipeline, i trigger a job like this:

```
        stage('Run downstream') {
          parallel {
            stage('partA') {
              steps {
                script {
                    if (env.GIT_BRANCH == 'origin/master') {
                        build job: 'downstream', wait: true
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            stage('partB') {
              steps {
                script {
                    if (env.GIT_BRANCH == 'origin/master') {
                        build job: 'downstream', wait: true, parameters: [
                          string(name: 'param', value: 'overriden value')
                        ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

the `downstream` job creates an artifact which I'd like to copy to the triggering job. How would  I get the build number for each invocation of the job so that I can pull their artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

I changed:

```
  build job: 'downstream', wait: true
```

to:

```
 triggeredBuild = build job: 'downstream', wait: true
 buildNumber = triggeredBuild.getNumber()
```